Moving to muslim country alternative
I wish to be a Fireman, for it's potential rewards, decent salary, and it's work schedule. I've heard that some scholars say it's haram to not move to a muslim country if you have the means. I wish to move to a muslim majority city in michigan in order to still be able to provide for me and a future wife with the salary and her not have to work, along with the other things I mentioned. If I move to a muslim country I may have to work a different, less noble job, islamically speaking, or my wife would need to work. Would my preffered course of action be justified, if it's for the sake of islam and my wife, assuming that the scholars I mentioned are correct.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].
